# pointer to pointer in struct. How to allocate memory in function

Tags: c

I have a struct like this

```
    struct abc{
      struct xyz **x;
    }
```

And create pointer to abc in main

```
     struct abc *o=(struct abc *)malloc(sizeof (struct abc));
```

and I am passing it to  function `hello`. want to pass `o->x` to a function `hello(struct xyz * xyz_obj)`

in function `hello` I want to allocate element with malloc call so I created function like this

```
        void hello(struct xyz **xyz_obj)
           {
               *xyz_obj=(struct xyz *)malloc(sizeof(struct xyz));}
```

but the problem is how to call `hello` so one element is added to the array.

I tried this function call like following to allocated o->x so in main I could use `o->xyz+some_number` but these tries not working

```
         hello(o->xyz+1); // NOT WORKING
         hello(*o->xyz+1) //NOT working
         hello((o)->xyz+1) //NOT working
         etc.
```

How I will allocate o-x in hello and use it in main

please add some explanation and way to accomplish this

Comment: You must _separately_ allocate memory for `x` inside `abc`.

Comment: Your struct doesn't have an array, it only has a pointer, which could point to an array. However, for that, you have to allocate an array first.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt of course thanks did it. was just checking

Comment: what about `hello(&o->xyz);`?

Comment: You cannot use `o->xyz` because `struct abc` doesn't have a member named `xyz`. Consider using `o->x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct xyz { /*something here*/ };

struct abc {
    struct xyz **x;
}

void hello(struct xyz **xyz_obj)
{
    // allocate one object of type struct xyz
    *xyz_obj = malloc(sizeof(struct xyz));
}

int main()
{
    // allocate an object of type struct abc
    struct abc *o = malloc(struct abc);
    // allocate storage for N pointers to struct xyz
    o->x = malloc(sizeof(struct xyz*) * N);

    hello(o->x    ); // first
    hello(o->x + 1); // second
    hello(o->x + 2); // third
    //... N times possible

    // access of object (of type struct xyz) at index n
    // o->x[n]->/*some field id*/;

    return 0;
}
```

You can't allocate `o->x` in the function `hello` (well you can allocate memory, but not assign it to `o->x`). For that, you have to refactor (that means, prototype of `hello` has to be re-declared and with that the calls to `hello`).

```
void hello(struct xyz ***xyz_obj)
{
    if (*xyz_obj == NULL)
        *xyz_obj = malloc(sizeof(struct xyz**) * N);

    // allocate one object of type struct xyz
    **xyz_obj = malloc(sizeof(struct xyz));
}

int main()
{
    //... same as before, but now we do not allocate any storage for o->x
    o->x = NULL;

    hello(&o->x); //since o->x is NULL, hello will allocate storage for o->x
    // hello(&(o->x + n));
    
    return 0;
}
```

I find the second approach ugly as hell. What is the benefit of it? Just to allocate any storage if it was not allocated before.

**Based on your questions in the comment section:**

```
struct xyz {
    char var;
};

struct abc {
    struct xyz **x;
};

int main() {

    // assume 'o' is initialized and 'o->x' is not NULL
    struct abc *o;

    // access 'var' of 'struct xyz' at position (index) 'n'
    o->x[n]->var = 'c';

    // or
    struct xyz *x = o->x[n];
    x->var = 'c';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: consider `char var` is inside `struct xyz` as member. How to use it like assign a value to it or `printf` it

Comment: also how to use it inside main

Comment: @666 I've added some more info to my answer based on your questions. Hope it helps further.